# C++ error: Call to non-constexpr function

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following C++ code (saved as example4.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr double nth(double x, int n);//initialization

int main()
{
double x=2;
int n=5;
nth(x,n);//Function call
return 0;
}


constexpr double nth(double x, int n)   // function definition
{
    double res = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i<n) {   // while-loop: do while the condition is true
         res*=x;
         ++i;
    }
cout << res;
cout << endl;
    return res;
}
```

This code is giving the following error:

```
> example4.cpp: In function ‘constexpr double nth(double, int)’:
> example4.cpp:24:9: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&
> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT =
> char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
> cout << res;
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Think of how hard it is to write to the user's console at compile time.

Comment: Consider removing the debug statements from the function and changing `nth(x,n);` to `cout << nth(x, n) << endl;`

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Streaming to `std::cout` is not allowed in a `constexpr` <s>function</s> context. In fact, only a limited set of things are. Read the [cppreference article on `constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: `std::cout <<` is allowed in a `constexpr` function and almost everything is, but there is another rule that requires a constant expression calling the `constexpr` function to exist in principle. A constant expression cannot execute a call to `std::cout <<`, but `nth` will *always* call `std::cout <<`, so it can never be used in a constant expression. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression.

Comment: For example, if OP adds `if(n<0) return 0;` at the top of the function body, then the program will have well-defined behavior and work as expected.

Comment: The insertion operators not marked `constexpr`, so doesn't that mean a call to those operators aren't allowed anywhere in a `constexpr` function body?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. If you look at the requirements you linked, you will see that there is no such requirement. The only requirement that OP is violating is "*there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression*" and this causes undefined behavior, so it is not required to be diagnosed by the compiler. Adding any execution path that would avoid the `std::cout <<` evaluation for some set of arguments (whether actually used or not) would make the program well-behaved.

Comment: So does that mean there just has to be at least one code path that does not contain any calls to non-`constexpr` functions, so long as only `constexpr` code paths are taken in `constexpr` contexts?

Comment: Yes (if you replace "*in constexpr contexts*" with "*in contexts requiring constant expressions*"), and OP's call `nth(x,n);` is not a context which requires a constant expression. In any case OP's call `nth(x,n);` would fail if it was required to be a constant expression anyway, because the `constexpr` function is not defined at the point of the call, which makes the call automatically not a constant expression. In any case, `constexpr` is certainly misused here.